# Driver problems with GeForce GT520

Tags: xorg, xserver, nvidia-geforce

I have a GeForce GT 520 dual head in my system and I was experimenting with it. I installed CUDA 9.1 from NVIDIA and it said I should reboot to verify that my graphics driver still loads.

So I rebooted and now, the graphics driver wouldn't load anymore, so I uninstalled, purged and autoremoved cuda again and rebooted again but I still can't get X back. I downloaded and tried to install the NVIDIA driver `NVIDIA_Linux_x86_64-367.27.run` but it doesn't want to install and instead tells me to run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-396 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-settings` which I tried too but I still cannot get back into my X.

How do I get my graphics back?

Comment: Will you edit your question and post the full exact error message you get when you run `NVIDIA_Linux_x86_64-367.27.run`?  Also, which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install nVidia drivers from ***.run files but instead from PPA like
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
so to omit any mess after...You already have messed things, also by installing 390 driver version You already have compiled cuda in there so no need to install additional cuda toolkit

Comment: "You already have a messed things" - how can I get the mess cleaned-up again?

Comment: I installed `nvidia-390` from the `graphics-drivers` paa from the link, rebooted and that brought my X back up! Solved! Thanks! (y)

Comment: I try to help not frustrate anybody :-) cool it helped!